# Converting the values of first columns to row names

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
dt <- structure(list(year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2009L), name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("stockA", "stockB"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("year", 
"name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I would like to produce a new df like this:

```
year stockA stockB
2008   1      1
2009   1      0
```

In order to make it I use this:

```
table(dt)
```

but it gives me only the stockA and stockB columns. How can I add the column with the years?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dt), year~name, length)
#    year stockA stockB
#1: 2008      1      1
#2: 2009      1      0
```

Comment: Did you read the question carefully? Half of your answer is already present in the question and the other half is a classic reshape from long to wide duplicate imo.

Comment: And I was saying that `dcast` is a very frequently asked question and definitely a duplicate.